# Remove all duplicate words from a row in text file by comparing with first column

Tags: linux, perl

**This is my input file:**

```
SC0001 : SC0001 SC0002 SC0001 
SC0004 : SC0004 SC0008 SC0001 SC0001 SC0004 SC0009 SC0000 SC0003 SC0002
SC0006 : SC0001 SC0006 SC0004 SC0005 SC0006 
SC0003 : SC0001 SC0003 
SC0008 : SC0008
SC0009 : SC0001 SC0009 SC0001 SC0001
```

**The output should be like this:**

```
 SC0001 : SC0002 
 SC0004 : SC0008 SC0001 SC0009 SC0000 SC0003 SC0002
 SC0006 : SC0001 SC0004 SC0005  
 SC0003 : SC0001  
 SC0008 : 
 SC0009 : SC0001 SC0001 SC0001
```

Comment: I think it might be helpful for you `How to remove duplicates is ).

    my %seen;
    my @unique = grep { ! $seen{$_}++ } @words;`

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe '%s=(); s/(\S+)/ $s{$1}++ ? "" : $1 /ge; s/ \K +//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick and dirty solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, "<", "test1.txt")
    or die "cannot open < file name: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my @elements = split(/ : /, $line);
    if ($#elements > -1) {
        $elements[1] =~ s/ ?$elements[0]//g;
        $line = join(" : ", @elements);
        $line =~ s/ {2,}/ /;
    }
    print $line;
}

close($fh);
```

### Input file

```
SC0001 : SC0001 SC0002 SC0001
SC0004 : SC0004 SC0008 SC0001 SC0001 SC0004 SC0009 SC0000 SC0003 SC0002
SC0006 : SC0001 SC0006 SC0004 SC0005 SC0006
SC0003 : SC0001 SC0003
SC0008 : SC0008
SC0009 : SC0001 SC0009 SC0001 SC0001
```

### Output

```
SC0001 : SC0002
SC0004 : SC0008 SC0001 SC0001 SC0009 SC0000 SC0003 SC0002
SC0006 : SC0001 SC0004 SC0005
SC0003 : SC0001
SC0008 : 
SC0009 : SC0001 SC0001 SC0001
```